# Trigger causes error (subquery return more than one value) on Bulk Insert

Tags: sql-server, triggers, bulkinsert

```
Alter Trigger [dbo].[DiscountUpdate] 
on [dbo].[t_PromoDtl]
Instead of insert
as
begin
    Declare @Barcode nvarchar(25);
    Declare @disper decimal(18,0);
    Declare @status int;
    Declare @BranchID nvarchar(15);

    set @Barcode = (Select barcodeFull from inserted); ---/// I think error happens in here.
    set @disper = (Select disPer from inserted);  ---/// I think error happens in here.
    set @status = (Select p.status from inserted p); ---/// I think error happens in here.

    begin
        if @status = 2
        begin
            update t_Prd  
            set PrdDiscnt = @disper 
            where BarcodeFull = @Barcode;
        end
        else
        begin
            update t_Prd  
            set PrdDiscnt = 0 
            where BarcodeFull = @Barcode;
        end
    end
end
```

Here is my C# code..

```
using (var sqlBulk3 = new SqlBulkCopy(_connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers |  SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints))
{
    using (SqlConnection con6 = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        con6.Open();

        SqlCommand cmdtt = new SqlCommand("Truncate Table t_PromoDtl", con6);
        cmdtt.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdtt.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con6.Close();
    }

    sqlBulk3.DestinationTableName = "t_PromoDtl";
    sqlBulk3.WriteToServer(PromoDtl);
}
```

When Bulk insert starts, the trigger throws this error:

> Sub query returns more than one value....

I looked at this trigger which updates `t_Prd` table instead of insert on `t_PromoDtl` table.

```
set @Barcode = (Select barcodeFull from inserted); ---/// I think error happens in here. 
set @disper = (Select disPer from inserted);  ---/// I think error happens in here.
set @status = (Select p.status from inserted p); ---/// I think error happens in here.
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select from `Inserted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to assume that the SQL Server trigger will be fired separately for each row - this is **NOT** the case - the trigger is fired **only once** for a statement. And if this is a `BULK INSERT`, then the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain **multiple rows** - so your statements like

```
set @Barcode = (Select barcodeFull from inserted);
```

are in fact the source of the problem - which one of the 250 rows inserted are you selecting here? It's not determined - you'll get back **one arbitrary** row - and what happens to the other 249 rows also inserted?? They're just plain ignored and not handled.

You need to **rewrite** your entire trigger logic to be **set-based** and handle the fact that the `Inserted` pseudo table will most likely contain multiple rows.

Try something like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DiscountUpdate] 
ON [dbo].[t_PromoDtl]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    -- update "dbo.T_Prd.PrdDiscnt" to "disPer" when status is 2
    UPDATE p
    SET PrdDiscnt = i.disPer
    FROM dbo.T_Prd p
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON i.BarcodeFull = p.BarcodeFull
    WHERE i.Status = 2;

    -- update "dbo.T_Prd.PrdDiscnt" to "0" when status is not 2
    UPDATE p
    SET PrdDiscnt = 0
    FROM dbo.T_Prd p
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON i.BarcodeFull = p.BarcodeFull
    WHERE i.Status <> 2;
```

I'm assuming here that `BarcodeFull` is your **primary key column** that uniquely identifies each row in your table - if that's not the case, you might need to adapt the JOIN condition to match your situation.

Comment: Hey @marc_s,  thanks for your support. But if i use 'instead of Insert' on Trigger  the 'Bulk insert' doesn't perform. It works fine on 'After insert' Trigger .